# Junit test with entity mananger

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am beginner in Unit Testing. I have a Java Web Application build in Netbeans 8.1 and Maven. I have created this class to try to test querys in  my PostgreSQl database:

```
public class DatesUtil {

    private Collection<Menusistema> listamenus = new LinkedList<>();

    private Menusistema menu= new Menusistema();

    private String nombreBuscar = null;

    private static final EntityManager entityManager;
    static {
        entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.controlpersonal.pu").
        createEntityManager();
    }

   public static EntityManager getEntityManager() { 
        return entityManager;
    };

    public DatesUtil() {

    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {


    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    // TODO add test methods here.
    // The methods must be annotated with annotation @Test. For example:
    //
     @Test
     public void hello() {
        buscarTodo();

     }


     public void buscarTodo(){
        findAll(Menusistema.class);
     }



    public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (List<T>) getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " p", clazz).getResultList();
    }  


}
```

I got the next error when I right click on netbeans and select: Test File:

> [EL Info]: 2018-04-30
>   20:30:57.78--ServerSession(252553541)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd [EL Severe]: ejb:
>   2018-04-30 20:30:57.836--ServerSession(252553541)--Exception
>   [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/controlpersonal].
>   Internal Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to
>   specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet
>   parameter, or in an application resource file: 
>   java.naming.factory.initial

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.controlpersonal.pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/controlpersonal</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I really would like to test if this is posible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `jta-data-source>jdbc/controlpersonal</jta-data-source>` - your production code is running in a container, it gets a data source from the container using jdni. So your test code must either also run within some (test?) container who will provide this datasorce through `jdbc/controlpersonal` jdni name, or you need to create and use another `persistence.xml` file under test/resorce/META-INF directory with a definition of the datasource which doesn;t use jdni (you can for example hardcode an url to the test database connection, user and passord).

Comment: Thanks @krokodilko your suggest works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  just created alternative persistente .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.controlpersonal.pu.test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!--<jta-data-source>jdbc/controlpersonal</jta-data-source>-->
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.your.class1</class>
        <class>com.your.class2</class>  
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="PostgreSQL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"     value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"     value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/controlpersonal" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit> </persistence>
```

Under: src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml